# Problem with TypeScript Methods and Virtual Mogoose Model in Next js 13.5

Tags: typescript, mongoose, next.js

I had this Model user.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import crypto from "crypto";
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        //Basic Data
        email: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        hashed_password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        salt: {
            type: String,
        },
        
);

// virtual field
userSchema
    .virtual("password")
    .set(function (password) {
        // create a temporarity variable called _password
        this._password = password;
        // generate salt
        this.salt = this.makeSalt();
        // encryptPassword
        this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
    })
    .get(function () {
        return this._password;
    });

//  Methods
userSchema.methods = {
    // Method Authenticate User
    authenticate: function (plainText) {
        const encryptP = this.encryptPassword(plainText);
        console.log("Entro a Autenticate...");
        console.log("Authenticate PlainText:", plainText);
        console.log("Authenticate Hashed:", this.hashed_password);
        console.log("Encript Pass:", encryptP);

        return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashed_password; //  Ture or False
    },
    // Method Encrypt Pass
    encryptPassword: function (password) {
        if (!password) return "";
        try {
            return crypto.createHmac("sha1", this.salt).update(password).digest("hex");
        } catch (err) {
            return "";
        }
    },

    // Method Make Salt
    makeSalt: function () {
        return Math.round(new Date().valueOf() * Math.random()) + "";
    },
};

// export default mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

The result of all console.log is:

```
Entro a Autenticate...
Authenticate PlainText: 1234567890
Authenticate Hashed: b4358d67e879145916c10ba00d66d78a946f4b53
Encript Pass: b4358d67e879145916c10ba00d66d78a946f4b53
```

The .js file works fine...

I start a new project using Typescript using the same logic and code but with typescript.

This is my model user.ts:

```
import { Model, model, Schema, models } from "mongoose";

import crypto from "crypto";

// 1. Create an interface representing a document in MongoDB.
interface IUser {
    email: string;
    hashed_password?: string;
    salt?: string;
    //Virtual Field
    _password?: string;
}

// Put all user instance methods in this interface:
interface IUserMethods {
    authenticate(plainText: string): boolean;
    encryptPassword(password: string): string;
    makeSalt(): string;
}

// Create a new Model type that knows about IUserMethods...
type UserModel = Model<IUser, {}, IUserMethods>;

// 2. Create a Schema corresponding to the document interface.
const userSchema = new Schema<IUser, UserModel, IUserMethods>(
    {
        //Basic Data
        
        email: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        hashed_password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        salt: {
            type: String,
        },
        
);

//Virtuals
userSchema
    .virtual("password")
    .set(function (password:string) {
        // create a temporarity variable called _password
        this._password = password;
        // generate salt
        this.salt = this.makeSalt();
        // encryptPassword
        this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
    })
    .get(function () {
        return this._password;
    });

//  Methods
userSchema.methods = {
    // Method Authenticate User
    authenticate: function (plainText:string) {
        const encryptP: any = this.encryptPassword(plainText);

        console.log("Entro a Autenticate...");
        console.log("Authenticate PlainText:", plainText);
        console.log("Authenticate Hashed:", this.hashed_password);
        console.log("Encript Pass:", encryptP);

        return this.encryptPassword(plainText) === this.hashed_password; //  Ture or False
    },
    // Method Encrypt Pass
    encryptPassword: function (password:string) {
        if (!password) return "";
        try {
            return crypto.createHmac("sha1", this.salt).update(password).digest("hex");
        } catch (err) {
            return "";
        }
    },
    // Method Make Salt
    makeSalt: function () {
        return Math.round(new Date().valueOf() * Math.random()) + "";
    },
};

export default models.User || model<IUser, UserModel>("User", userSchema);
```

the result of all the console logs whit this Typescript file is:

```
Entro a Autenticate...
Authenticate PlainText: 1234567890
Authenticate Hashed: undefined
Encript Pass:
```

The problem appears to be in the way it is handle the types...

But not a clue...

EDITED:

Based on the comments, I found that the issue is whit:

```
    this.salt
    this.hashed_password
```

in TS is shown as "undefined" in JS as a string (as should be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

The problem was not Typescript, was the OBJECT "this" , this object is created when the method is called.

So the method is call like this

```
userDB.authenticate(passIn);
```

The userDB object on mongoose is the "this" object mounted. So, the this.salt and this.hashed_password must be contained on the userDB object to "Exists" on the Method called.

The userDB object mounted on "this" did not contains salt and hashed_pass so I add them and the code WORKS just fine!

Comment: In that case, please select the answer and mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with this code. I'll go through them one-by-one, but before that, your code is likely not working because in `crypto.createHmac("sha1", this.salt)`, `this.salt` may be undefined or a different type than what the function expects. Please log the error in your catch block instead of simply returning the empty string. That should help.
Moving on to the issues:

#### The Salt

In the following line:

```
return crypto.createHmac("sha1", this.salt).update(password).digest("hex");
```

`this.salt` is not the salt, it is the key. An HMAC is essentially a keyed hash. The second argument of the `createHmac` function expects the key to generate the hash. You will later need this same key to verify the hash.
You can use it to achieve the same thing as a salt in that you can thwart rainbow table attacks, but it is not exactly the same thing, in that a key is supposed to be secret while a salt is not.

#### The Algorithm

If you're hashing user passwords, **please do not use SHA-1**. It is considered broken. [OWASP password storage cheat sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html) has recommendations on how to store passwords, what hash functions to use with what parameters, etc. Argon2id or scrypt should be fine.

#### The `makeSalt` function

I hope the implementation of this function was rushed for demo / debugging purposes, but in case it was not, please do not create a salt like this. A better way to create a random salt would be to use the `crypto.randomBytes` function. In case you want a string, you can just call `toString` on it with the relevant encoding. For example, for hex you can do this:

```
// generate a 16 byte random salt
const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
return salt;
```

Comment: I made some corrections to the code... and tried as you suggest but the result is the same: Entro a Autenticate...
Authenticate PlainText: 1234567890
Authenticate Hashed: undefined
Encript Pass:                                    I think the problem could be something with de typescript use of "this."

Comment: I have edited my answer. I ran your code locally and while I ran it by directly calling the `authenticate` method, the issue I saw was that `this.salt` was undefined, which was throwing an error, and since the catch block did nothing except returning an empty string, the code just moved on without logging anything.

Also, `this` in TypeScript is no different than `this` in JavaScript. TS transpiles to JS and the code which ends up running is JS. TS just adds some checks / features for your convenience during development. It does not impact runtime behaviour in any way.

Comment: Exactly as you write... the error shows this: RROR EN ENCRYPTADO >>> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of ArrayBuffer, Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, KeyObject, or CryptoKey. Received undefined...........

Comment: I don't like the method used to "Secure" the users and passwords on DB, but I already have some users on the DB whit passwords encrypted and storage with this method... so if I want the transition to Typescript will no affect them I must use the same method to validate encrypt and validate ... or what you recommend?

Comment: If you can try the code in Javascript you can notice that works just fine... so I think is something whit the TypeScript Types that is missing or wrong...

Comment: @MiguelAngelMarroquinJordan The JS code you've provided behaves the same way as the TS code for me, at least when I directly call the `authenticate` function.

Comment: I found the solution, thanks for your help! ... the problem was on the "this" object mounted when the method is called...